# How to get an average of multiple cells, while ignoring blanks and zeros when factoring the average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Trying to get monthly numbers average. But on weeks that have no numbers, because it is too early in the month there are no numbers for 2 weeks, for example. there is a Zero or NA in those cells. How would I calculate that so there Month ending Average does not give #Div/0!
The multiple cells I’m averaging are not continuos and are on different sheets. I know AverageIF is the start.

Comment: [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) or [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/averageifs-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690) should do what you want

Comment: Ok. I forgot to add that these cells are not continuous. Some cells are on different sheets

Comment: you can use something like: `=AVERAGE(IF((ISNUMBER(1stRange))*(1stRange<>0),1stRange,""),IF((ISNUMBER(2ndRange))*(2ndRange<>0),2ndRange,""),...)` depending on version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-shift-Enter.

Comment: So to Average for cells on different sheets, I basically have to enter that I’m multiplying them and dividing by how many I’m assuming. And when I insert the <>0, “”, it will not factor in for the average ?

Comment: That is not what my formula does.  It creates a bunch of arrays of numbers that are not 0 and `""`.  AVERAGE will ignore the `""` as if they are not part of the range completely.